# Does a PHP static anonymous function really work?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I'm trying to learn PHP, and now I'm stuck in 'static anonymous function'.

I found this in a tutorial (http://www.slideshare.net/melechi/php-53-part-2-lambda-functions-closures-presentation)

> "Object Orientation
>
> - Lambda Functions are Closures because they automatically get bound to the scope of the class that they are created in.
> - '`$this`' is not always needed in the scope.
> - Removing '`$this`' can save on memory.
> - You can block this behaviour by declaring the Lambda Function as static."

What is wrong with this code?

I get this error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM' in C:\wamp\www\z-final\a.php on line 11

Why this code line doesn't work "return static function(){var_dump($this);};" ?

```
class foo
{
    public function getLambda()
    {
        return function(){var_dump($this);};
    }

    public function getStaticLambda()
    {
        return static function(){var_dump($this);};
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$lambda = $foo->getLambda();
$staticLambda = $foo->getStaticLambda();
$lambda();
$staticLambda();
```

Comment: The `static` keyword between `return` and `function()` is the problem, what did you tried to achieve?

Comment: No it's not. The problem is not using PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 43):

Yes, that is perfectly valid syntax in 5.4+.

Basically, it prevents auto-binding of the current class to the closure (in fact, it prevents all binding, but more on that later).

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        return static function() { var_dump($this); };
    }
    public function baz() {
        return function() { var_dump($this); };
    }
}
```

If we instantiate that on 5.4+, the closure `bar()` returns will have `$this` set to null. Just as if you made a static call to it. But `baz()` would have `$this` set to the foo instance you called `baz()` on.

So:

```
$bar = $f->bar();

$bar();
```

Results in:

> Notice: Undefined variable: this in /in/Bpd3d on line 5
>
> NULL

And

```
$baz = $f->baz();

$baz();
```

Results in

> object(Foo)#1 (0) {
>
> }

Make sense? Great.

Now, what happens if we take closures defined outside of a function:

```
$a = function() { var_dump($this); };
$a();
```

We get `null` (and a notice)

```
$c = $a->bindTo(new StdClass());
$c();
```

We get `StdClass`, just as you'd expect

```
$b = static function() { var_dump($this); };
$b();
```

We get `null` (and a notice)

```
$d = $b->bindTo(new StdClass());
$d();
```

This is where things get interesting. Now, we get a warning, a notice, and null:

> Warning: Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in /in/h63iF on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: this in /in/h63iF on line 9
>
> NULL

So in 5.4+, you can declare a static closure, which results in it never getting `$this` bound to it, nor can you ever bind an object to it...

Comment: Please note, as of PHP 7.1 all notices and warnings in the above answer are treated as `Fatal errors`

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to define it with the `static` keyword.

```
<?php
class House
{
     public function paint($color)
     {
         return function() use ($color) { return "Painting the house $color..."; };
     }
}

$house = new House();
$callback = $house->paint('red');
var_dump($callback); // object(Closure)#2 (2) {..}
var_dump($callback()); // "Painting the house red..."
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `static` instead of `strict`?

Comment: he's asking about syntax error not whether he should use a static anon function. static anon is not the same as anon.