# What means keyword "static" in defining anonymous function?

Tags: php, promise, guzzle

While learning guzzlehttp I noticed code with `static` keyword before anonymous functions. Phpstorm shows errors before and after `static`, seems that editor is confused too :)

```
$value->then(
    static function ($value) use ($handlers) {
        ...
    },
    static function ($reason) use ($handlers) {
        ...
    }
);
```

What does it mean and what is the difference between usual anonymous function?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is that you're not able to access `$this` from within the function. Kinda like a protection against misuse to avoid hacky modules / plugins.

Comment: Generally speaking, it means that the function isn't handed an object (an instantiation of a class) when it's called. Thus, you can't use `$this` (`self` in python) within the function/method. It's handy for utility functions that could also have been placed outside the class in the global name-space. E.g. a function that checks whether or not a given number is prime probably doesn't need to be handed an entire object. Prime is prime and the result won't change no matter where you place the function. Check the [php docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579657/does-a-php-static-anonymous-function-really-work

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now